# Eclipse, mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse, Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

Problem :
Error: Could not find or load main class

Situation :

1. Spring Boot Project
2. Latest Version of Eclipse, Maven 3.3.1, JDK 1.8.0.242
3. Windows 10
4. Eclipse Build 2019-12

How to reporduce

1. Go to parent of my project
2. Run `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`
3. Import the projects as `Existing projects in workspace` ( I do not want to use Maven Project )
4. Go to my main class
5. Right Click Run -> Run As -> Check the Main Class its correct
6. Error: Could not find or load main class

Already tried :

1. Many times clean run mvn clean install mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
2. Delete .meta and recreate workspace many times
3. Went to Run as -> Classpath -> Advance -> Add Folder -> Add target/classes
4. Since I am writing this question, I apparently tried everything on StackOverflow related to this issue.

I appreciate if someone can recommend something new .

[ Update ]

The problem is resolved for all the builds other than 2019-12.
I have verified for the following

- Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13)
- Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12)
- Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11)

Comment: Try doing project -> clean in Eclipse twice

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I have done these numerous times . Clean All projects , Build all Project etc.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project exactly twice one after the other? Is there any other project which works fine in your eclipse? Is your eclipse pointing to correct JDK and not JRE?

Comment: Yes, I clean it twice. Infact if I do this 'New -> Java Project ' and then create a class 'Something.java' and write a main method with Hello World, it works absolutely fine

Comment: There might be problems with your project's classpath. You can try **1)** Right-click on the project > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Move the `src/` folder entry up or **2)** check in your project's _.classpath_ file that paths are relative and/or do not point to non-existing directories

Comment: my xxxx/src/main/java is first and xxxxx/src/main/resources is the second . 2. Most of the entry in my classpath are M2_REPO and then the jar name like that. There is no , non existing jar file because .. I do this . git clean -fxd ; mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse. Everything used to work fine but stopped working when I downloaded the newest eclipse

Comment: Instead of doing `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` and importing it as Eclipse project (this is not recommended for years) let Eclipse conifgure the project: _File > Import Projects from File System..._.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but then it doesnot detect any main class. Meaning if I Run as , there is a dialogue box saying editor doesnot contain any main class

Comment: @here Thank you all for your suggestion, but the situation is resolved if I switch to any other build  THAN 2019-12.

Comment: I confirm my app is working properly for these versions: Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13)
Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12)
Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11)

Comment: Do not do trial and error, but find and fix the root cause. If you face the error _"Could not find or load main class"_, it's probably because the class will not be compiled and the question is, what prevents the class from being compiled?

Comment: Hello Howlger , thank you for your suggestion. I do spent sufficient time to debug and frame the problem so that I can file a bug. But I cannot reach to a conclusion. YES , the class files do complie in my output folder , '/target/classes' ( I change it ). I highly suspect that the problem is the classpath file generated by mvn eclipse plugin. I have a plan to create a test project on weekend and reproduce the problem so that I can file a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question convinced me. This only happen **2019-12**.
I have verified for the following.

- Spring suite 3
- Spring suite 4
- Eclipse Photon

The cause of the problem is due to restrictions on classpaths that are limited by OS.
 - This is a one of related with this issue [Java: Support for long classpath on Windows](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2242).

You can solve the problem by setting the options for the classpath as shown below.(or from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.9/jdt.php) )
[image]
In Spring Tool Suite 3,4 it works without any special configuration.

I haven't found a way to visually identify the problem yet.

**This problem is unique.**
There's nothing wrong with builds or deploys, it's only a problem when debugging.
So it's easy to tell if it's a problem with the classpath or not.